# How to enable structure guide line for html in visual studio 17?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oDvc.png)

I have turned it on from Options->Text Editors->General->Show Structure guide lines . 
It works for other languages but html files.